# installing DirectX 9 on Windows 10 (i5 8600k 16GB 3200 RAM 512GB SSD GTX1060)

Tags: direct3d, directx-9

I wanted to run the Nvidia CUDA samples for my GTX1060 using Visual Studio 2017 Community. Mostly this was straightforward; I downloaded the CUDA samples, opened VS 2017 using the supplied "2017.sln" file, rebuilt everything and off we go...

Unfortunately the samples based on DirectX 9 didn't build, so following protocol I started the hunt on the internet at the usual suspects e.g. MSDN, Tom's Hardware etc.,. Lots of good stuff but no one-stop solution.

How do I setup and run the DirectX 9 samples?

Comment: If you could format this as a question (above) and answer (below) pair then it would be better. You should consider taking the [tour].

Comment: I have reposted your solution from your question as a (quoted) answer. If you want to create your own fully fledged answer then please do so and I will delete mine so that you can get the rep in future.

Answer (score 0):

Moved from the question:

> Here is what I did :
>
> 1. download the Direct X 9 June 2010 SDK from MSDN.
> 2. try to run the installer - get the error "...requires Net 2.0 and 3.5"
> 3. try to install Net 2.0 - get another error...
> 4. search a bit more - inspiration, install "Net 2.0 Redistributable" - 
>        works!
> 5. try the DX9 installer again - get the message "..requires Net 3.5 - do you 
>        want to install it ?". Clearly "yes". Works!
> 6. try the DX9 installer again - YES, YES, YES!!!
> 7. fix up the project files in VS 2017 to refer to the DX9 SDK include 
>        directories and one missing reference to "d3dx9math.h" in a ".cpp" source 
>        file and VOILA!
>
> I wish I could say this little recipe would fix the job for every
>   case, but I  hope it might just nudge someone else trying to get this
>   working to another  option before giving it up as a bad job